# Increment field within validator

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a custom validator that checks if the user has entered the correct SMS code. When the user enters the wrong code I need to log the failed attempt and limit their retries to 3 per code.

I have created the following validator that works however the field is not being incremented.

```
  def token_match
    if token != User.find(user_id).verification_token
      User.find(user_id).increment!(:verification_fails)
      errors.add(:sms_code, "does not match")
    end
  end
```

The problem is as soon as I add the error the previous statement is rolled back. If I comment out the errors.add line then the increment works however there is no higher level validation performed.

Comment: You're abusing validators. Don't use them for this check, use simple methods on the model

Comment: Thanks. What if I need business logic to be satisfied before the record can be saved? The only validation required is presence: true however if the user has already tried 3 times unsuccessfully then the record should not be updated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `#update_columns` in your validator. It writes directly to db.

```
u = User.find(user_id)
u.update_columns(verification_fails: u.verification_fails + 1)
```

This worked for me. But if for some reason it doesn't work for you, maybe you can try running it in a new thread,which creates a new db connection:

```
Thread.new do
  num = User.find(user_id).verification_fails
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.with_connection { |con| con.exec_query("UPDATE users SET verification_fails = #{num} WHERE id = #{user_id}") }
end.join
```

Comment: Didn't work. update_column gets rolled back when I add the message to the errors collection.

Comment: Updated my answer. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Change your custom validator to be:

```
  def token_match
    if token != User.find(user_id).verification_token
      errors.add(:sms_code, "does not match")
    end
  end
```

and add in your model `after_validation` callback to be like this:

```
after_validation: increase_fails_count

    def increase_fails_count
      unless self.errors[:sms_code].empty?
        user = User.find_by(:id => user_id)
        user.increment!(:verification_fails)
        user.save
      end
    end
```

Comment: still gets rolled back when using an after_validation callback

Comment: @Dercni try to call user.save explicitly as per my revised answer

Comment: Wouldn't #save trigger validation again?